# Back wheel tube consistently popping when putting wheel back on bike

Tags: innertube, puncture, road

I ride a Specialized Allez that's probably 15 years old, and recently had to purchase new wheels and tires because mine were stolen. I put a new tube on my new back wheel, and it popped as soon as I started tightening the quick release after putting it back on the bike. I bought a new tube, installed it, and the same thing happened. So I got another tube, installed it on the wheel, and let it sit for a week. It held air perfectly. Then I put the wheel back on my bike, and it was flat within an hour. Every pop has been at the stem of the presta valve or within the valve itself. Any ideas on what might be causing this? More info: all three tubes were presta, and I thought I checked the rim and tire for sharp objects fairly well.

Comment: Please try lightly rubbing your finger on the inside of the rim around the valve hole.  It should feel "rounded" or "soft" with no sharp edges, and no corners.   Second, are you using Presta valves in a Schrader-sized hole?  That sometimes works, but not always.   Lastly, how's the rim tape?  Any wrinkles or edges poking up ?   A photo of the area might help.

Comment: Also, inflating the tube outside the tyre is an excellent idea and shows they're not immediately flawed.  However the pressure attained unconstrained by a tyre might reach ~5 PSI, compared to the regular pressure you might run when installed.

Comment: Lastly - you said "Every pop has been at the stem of the presta valve or within the valve itself"   There's no holes on the "inward facing" side of the tube at all?   The damage is around or in the valve ?

Comment: Criggie, thanks so much for your responses. I should have said that I inflated the tube while it was installed in the tire on the wheel, and left that for a week. Let me look into things you suggested and get back to you. Again, thanks so much.